# Is cookie authentication supported in nestjs swagger?

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, nestjs, openapi

I want to include cookie authorization in my swagger docs, however I seem to be making no progress.

According to https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/security there looks as though cookie auth is supported in nestjs-swagger.

However, according to https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/cookie-authentication/ for Swagger UI and Editor, cookie auth is not supported for "try it out"

I am unsure if I am implementing cookie auth incorrectly or if it is just not supported.

Bellow is the implementation I am trying.

In the DocumentBuilder():

```
.addCookieAuth('authCookie')
```

In controller:

```
@ApiCookieAuth()
```

I've tried adding my cookie name 'authCookie' to the @ApiCookieAuth() tag.
I have also tried using `.addCookieAuth('authCookie', {type: 'apiKey',in: 'cookie'})`

Any way I try I get a JWT token not found error. I know this does work when I use postman so I am confused as to why I am getting this issue.

Answer (score 1):

### An solition for me was to use such `options` in the `DocumentBuilder`:

```
.addCookieAuth('authCookie', {
  type: 'http',
  in: 'Header',
  scheme: 'Bearer'
})
```

And such decorator in controller:

```
@ApiCookieAuth()
```

---

### In case you need to specify the cookie name there is a `securityName` parameter which will specify the name of cookie **in-app**

```
.addCookieAuth(cookieName?: string, options?: SecuritySchemeObject, securityName?: string)
```

After You will specify a `securityName` You will also need to provide it to a contoller decorator:

In the `DocumentBuilder`:

```
.addCookieAuth('auth-cookie', {
  type: 'http',
  in: 'Header',
  scheme: 'Bearer'
},
'in-app-cookie-name')
```

In controller:

```
@ApiCookieAuth('in-app-cookie-name')
```

---

### This solution is working **only** after a manual insertion the JWT into a swagger auth input. If I get it right - SwaggerUI don`t support automatically insert of the cookie fields.

[link with this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/issues/1163)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can just use

```js
  SwaggerModule.setup('swagger', app, document, {
    swaggerOptions: {
      requestInterceptor: (req) => {
        req.credentials = 'include';
        return req;
      },
    },
  });
```

Please note, that setting cookie value manually will not have any effect on Fetch request.

It is related to `swagger-client`, not to `NestJs`